# Where does adb shell mkdir create directories

Tags: android

I tried:

```
$ adb shell
# mkdir data/local/tmp/testjars
# exit
```

I thought **testjars** would be created in the current working directory, but nothing appears there. Where is this folder I created (**testjars**) placed?

Comment: It is created at data/local/tmp. If you just execute `mkdir testjars` it will be created in the current working directory

Comment: I'm using android virtual device. I have no  phone connected to my PC. What is the full path of **data/local/tmp**?

Comment: I think that's already the full path, but you can always try `cd data/local/tmp/;pwd`

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev Did my answer helped you to solve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

It will be created in whatever directory is your *current working directory* (inside the adb shell, not your host system).

Example:

```
adb shell # execute shell, the following commands are executed inside it
cd /data/local/tmp # change the current working directory to the temp directory
mkdir data/local/tmp/testjars # create a new directory(ies)
```

After the execution of the commands above, the path to the `testjars` directory will be following: `/data/local/tmp/data/local/tmp/testjars`.

So better do:

```
adb shell
cd /data/local/tmp # change the current working directory to where you want to create a subdirectory
mkdir testjars
```

You'll end up with a directory `/data/local/tmp/testjars`.

Also, if you specify the path without a starting slash `/`, e.g. `mkdir test`, it's created in the current working directory. If you specify it *with* the starting slash, e.g. `mkdir /test`, it's created in the root directory (if you have rights to do that).